# Dynamic loading of images R.Drawable using variable

Tags: android

I think i'm getting closer but still getting resource errors with this. I have an image file named rock.png in all 3 drawable folders.

in my layout MAIN.XML:

```
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/rockId" android:src="@drawable/rock"></ImageView>
```

In my code:

```
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("rockId" , "id", "com.testing");
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(resID);
```

I'm still seeing this in my error catlog:

```
10-30 17:36:24.485: WARN/ResourceType(74): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f020000
```

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong? Any tips welcome

Answer (score 26, accepted):

to find the control:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rockId);
```

To dynamicly load an image from drawable i use this function

```
    public static int getDrawable(Context context, String name)
    {
        Assert.assertNotNull(context);
        Assert.assertNotNull(name);

        return context.getResources().getIdentifier(name,
                "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    }
```

this will return the id of your drawable, now all you need to to is set the image in the control:

```
image.setImageResource(int Id);
```