# Use dynamic filename in Android R.drawable.<filename>

Tags: android, image, android-drawable

I'm trying to dynamically construct the filename of an image in Android to use in the R.drawable. clause.

Here's my code:

```
    imgHouse = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    strHouseNameImageFile = strHouseName + ".png";
    imgHouse.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.<filename>);
```

And in the last line above, I really want it to be a combination of the house name and .png but I'm not sure how to put a string together that will be used by R.drawable.

Could I do something like this for the last line, which now gives an error in Android Studio:
        imgHouse.setBackgroundResource(strHouseNameImageFiles);

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have to add `.png`? If the file is located in `drawable` you don't have to add the extension name.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int iconResId = getResources().getIdentifier(strHouseName, "drawable",getPackageName());

imgHouse.setImageResource(iconResId);
```

Comment: Hi Akash - what is setImageResource? I'm getting a Can not resolve on it.

Comment: I get it now, I had the wrong object trying to use setImageResource. I try that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to set the background resource may not work since the R class is generated at compile time. The R.drawable.***  is really an integer which is generated at compile time. The closest match to your problem may be this post : [Dynamic loading of images R.Drawable using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948059/dynamic-loading-of-images-r-drawable-using-variable)