# Installing pictures in Android

Tags: android, image, file, bitmap, imageview

Right now I have a folder /assets/ where I've been placing a bunch of .png files.

I recently had a developer make some new assets for me -- they came in the format (to use an example):

```
/mdpi/example_asset.png
/xhdpi/example_asset@2x.png
```

Do these need to go in the `/res/drawable/` folders (such as `/res/drawable-mdpi/`)? Do I have to change my code entirely to use these asset files instead of the ones in my /asset/ folder?

Normally I've been doing this to get a Bitmap from the assets folder (e.g. for something like `/assets/example_asset.png`):

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(Context context, String fileName) {
    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();

    InputStream istr;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        istr = assetManager.open(fileName + ASSET_FILE_EXTENSION);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Could not get bitmap for asset image "  + fileName + ": " + e);
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

What all must I change, here?

Comment: Why the downvote? Tough crowd!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use them as drawables, they need to go in the right folders.  If you aren't using them as drawables, you can use it as an asset.  However, asset files don't have size overrides.  If you want to use different versions of the image for different sized devices, you should use them as drawables.

Really when you're talking images I see no reason to use them as assets, as the drawable system is almost always more convenient.

Comment: What do I have to do instead, code-wise? Right now, for instance, I am mapping `/assets/example_asset.png` to a Bitmap and applying that to an ImageView. I imagine instead I have to do something else if now I am pulling from Drawable and not Assets?

Comment: Its actually easier.  Use imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.filename).  That's it, no reading in the bitmap.

Comment: Am I allowed to include my own subfolders for easier management? For example `/res/drawable-xhdpi/cityIcons/someCityFile.png` versus `/res/drawable-xhdpi/farmIcons/someFarmFile.png`? Or must everything get grouped together in one giant clustermuffin?

Comment: No, you can't.  I wish you could.

Comment: What if the argument is dynamic though? It doesn't let you do R.drawable. + customName for example? Is this the right way? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7948209/7368066

Comment: That way does work.  Of course if you need that, that's a good argument for keeping it in assets.

Comment: Is there some downside to doing it that way (in the link)?